# Win32 - CreateDialogParam returns before or after WM_INITDIALOG

Tags: winapi, dialog

I am passing a pointer to a string to a DialogProc via CreateDialogParam. This pointer points to dynamically allocated memory which is released immediately after CreateDialogParam returns. Is WM_INITDIALOG processed before CreateDialogParam returns?

For example:

```
LPWSTR lpStr = malloc( some_size )
CreateDialogParam( ... lpStr );
free( lpStr );
```

In DialogProc:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
  ... do something with lParam
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to [the documentation for CreateDialogParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> The CreateDialogParam function uses the CreateWindowEx function to create the dialog box. CreateDialogParam then sends a WM_INITDIALOG message ... to the dialog box procedure.

The operative word here is that it *sends* a message (as opposed to posting one). SendMessage just calls the dialog procedure directly. PostMessage would put the message in the queue.

So, yes, the WM_INITDIALOG should complete before CreateDialogParam returns. You can verify this yourself relatively trivially using a debugger and some breakpoints.

Comment: Ah, good to see someone who understands the difference between sent and posted.

Comment: I was unsure about whether the `send` it referred to was SendMessage or just the colloquial definition without defining the order. Your suggestion on breaking is something I should have thought of earlier though :)

Comment: The difference between "send" and "post" is so important to Windows programming that even the people who write the documentation know about it!

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa928175.aspx

> The CreateDialogParam function uses the CreateWindowEx function to create the dialog box. CreateDialogParam then sends a WM_INITDIALOG message to the dialog box procedure. The function displays the dialog box if the template specifies the WS_VISIBLE style. Finally, CreateDialogParam returns the window handle of the dialog box.

This states that WM_INITDIALOG is sent to the dialog before it completes. However, this message isn't processed until the window message loop on the dialog fetches the message. Since you're working with two separate threads, you shouldn't rely on this behaviour. If a slow operation is being executed synchronously on the window message loop, it might take longer than the rest of the CreateWindowEx call.

EDIT: As per Joel's answer, the documentation does imply that it sends (blocking) the message rather than posting it. You should test it yourself before relying on any functionality.

Comment: That's a non-queued synchronous message. No message queue involved.

Comment: Is it explicitly specified as synchronous anywhere, or is that just implied from their use of "sent" vs "posted"?

Comment: Even MS are sloppy in their terminology sometimes and may say sent when they mean posted, but that's a synchronous message. System would not work if it was queued.